# spring-boot JPA repository for multiple sources

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have data from two sources 1.From database 2.External server using REST

I have written JPA repository for data database

```
public interface DeviceRepository extends JpaRepository<Devices, Long> {
  List<Devices> findByActivation(boolean active);
  List<Devices> findByDeviceId(int id);
}
```

Second kind of data I need to get from REST

```
   List<UserDevices> userDevices = // send http request to get this data 

  List<Devices> devices= tutorialRepository.findByActivation(true)
  for(usermap : userDevices) 
     { 
     // iterate over and join these two  

     }
```

due to some restriction we can not source the REST data to samedb, Is there any better option to join these information ?